# Format mongoId for the frontend

Tags: mongodb, express, ember.js, mongoose

MongoDb returns ids of the form `_id`. I would like to make sure that the frontend (ember.js app) always receives `id` instead. I could write a serializer on the client, but I think there's probably a much easier solution that could either be implemented at the Database level or within the express server app.

I tried using virtual attributes, but this did'nt seem to work.

```
ActionSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  title: type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
  reduction: type: Number
  description: type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
  category: type: String
)

ActionSchema.virtual('id').get(->
  @_id
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using custom `toJSON` method. In model after schema declaration:

```
schema.options.toJSON =
  transform: (doc, ret, options) ->
    ret.id = ret._id
    delete ret._id
    delete ret.__v
    ret
```

Then in my controller I've used `item.toJSON()` when I wanted to return correctly formatted JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer using this blog post:
http://ryanchristiani.com/working-with-ember-data-node-express-and-mongodb/

The simple way is to write a rest serializer in Ember like so:

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: '_id',
    serializeId: function(id) {
        return id.toString();
    }
});
```